# Cruisecontrol.net dependencies

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have a question about dependencies in CCNET. I have several projects, each of them are dependant on another project (a control library as it is referred to internally). When the control library project is changed, and triggers a recompile, how do I get the other dependent projects to be rebuilt?

Comment: I know I have flagged the answer, but I still cannot get this to work. We have a rather complex hierarchy where there are lots of little base projects that are depenencies for large projects, our actual applications. Can I have multiple triggers ?

Comment: I thought I would update this question, as I have now got this to work, so thanks once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [project triggers](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Project+Trigger).

Comment: Great, I don't know how long I looked at the documentation, but still didn't find that section.

Answer (score 0):

We also have many interdependent projects too, which we solve by telling MSBuild to build a solution file which contains all the projects requires, and in the appropriate build order.